How to handle jstree when using Selenium with python?
I have been working on a web scraping project with selenium. My webpage uses jstrees. In my webpage has select button. Then, a container comes to the webpage. There are jstree structures inside the container. What is the best method for me?
loc_select_button=driver.find_element(By.ID, 'locationBTN')
loc_select_button.click()

modal=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"modal-content")))


all_locs_container=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.ID,"ModalTreeView_container"))


all_locs_show=all_locs_container.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jstree-icon jstree-ocl")
all_locs_show.click()


all_stations_container=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.ID,"ModalTreeView_container"))

I have been tried click and show as usual. But, jstree can be open/closed.
Thank you for helping.
